# Can I pass a lists of lists (or matrix) by reference in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, matrix, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to alter the contents of this list of lists using the function changeGrid(). Each character inside should be replaced with 'X' and the grid should be changed globally. Is it possible to do this? I've seen this done when the variable is an object, but I'm not sure what to do for a matrix such as this. Thanks.

```js
var grid =  [['T', 'W', 'Y', 'R'],
             ['E', 'N', 'P', 'H'],
             ['G', 'Z', 'Qu', 'R'],
             ['O', 'N', 'T', 'A']];


function changeGrid(table){
    table = [
        [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' ],
        [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' ],
        [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' ],
        [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' ]
      ]
    return table
}

console.log(grid)
console.log(changeGrid(grid));
console.log(grid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already being passed by reference. You will need to do a forEach (or something similar). Below is a quick and dirty solution:

```js
var grid =  [['T', 'W', 'Y', 'R'],
             ['E', 'N', 'P', 'H'],
             ['G', 'Z', 'Qu', 'R'],
             ['O', 'N', 'T', 'A']];


function changeGrid(table){
    table.forEach((e1, i1) => e1.forEach((e2, i2) => table[i1][i2] = 'X'))
}

console.log(grid)
changeGrid(grid);
console.log(grid);
```